# How to set boundary of a TextBlock in a grid?

Tags: c#, uwp, grid, uwp-xaml, textblock

I have few textblocks in a grid which can be dragged. I want to restrict the user so that user can't drag a textblock outside the grid.

I've tried a few ways like getting the position of the grid so that somehow i can control but it didn't work as expected.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show what logic are you using to drag the `TextBlock`s?

Comment: private void runtime_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.transform.TranslateX += e.Delta.Translation.X;
            this.transform.TranslateY += e.Delta.Translation.Y;
        }

In TextBlock added:
transform = (CompositeTransform)textBlock.RenderTransform;

Comment: why can't you use logic to determine whether the point is inside or outside your expected boundary, and if it's outside, then skip changing `TranslateX`

Comment: @Muzib :-  How do we get expected boundary of grid ?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done pretty easily using a `Canvas` inside the `Grid`, calculating the coordinates of the `TextBlock` inside of the `Canvas` and then continuously checking whether the `TextBlock` is still within its bounds. When the `TextBlock` leaves its bounds, the `Transform` then reverts back to it's last known 'good' coordinates.

XAML

```
<Grid>
    <Grid Name="GridBounds" Width="600" Height="600" Background="Aqua">
        <Canvas>
            <TextBlock Name="TextBlock1" Text="Drag Me" FontSize="40" ManipulationDelta="TextBlock1_ManipulationDelta" ManipulationMode="TranslateX, TranslateY" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Canvas.Left="216" Canvas.Top="234" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Code Behind

```
    CompositeTransform TextDrag = new CompositeTransform();
    CompositeTransform savedTransform = new CompositeTransform();

    public MainPage()
    {          
        this.InitializeComponent();
        TextBlock1.RenderTransform = TextDrag;
    }

    // Copy Transform X and Y if TextBlock is within bounds
    private void CopyTransform(CompositeTransform orig, CompositeTransform copy)
    {
        copy.TranslateX = orig.TranslateX;
        copy.TranslateY = orig.TranslateY;
    }


    private void TextBlock1_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextDrag.TranslateX += e.Delta.Translation.X;
        TextDrag.TranslateY += e.Delta.Translation.Y;           

        CompositeTransform transform = TextBlock1.RenderTransform as CompositeTransform;

        // Get current Top-Left coordinates of TextBlock
        var TextTopLeft = TextBlock1.TransformToVisual(GridBounds).TransformPoint(new Point(0, 0));

        // Get current Bottom-Right coordinates of TextBlock
        var TextBottomRight = TextBlock1.TransformToVisual(GridBounds).TransformPoint(new Point(TextBlock1.ActualWidth, TextBlock1.ActualHeight));

        // Get Top-Left grid coordinates
        var GridTopLeft = (new Point(0, 0));

        // Get Bottom-Right grid coordinates
        var GridBottomRight = (new Point(GridBounds.ActualWidth, GridBounds.ActualHeight));

        if (TextTopLeft.X < GridTopLeft.X || TextBottomRight.X > GridBottomRight.X)
        {
            // Out of bounds on X axis - Revert to copied X transform
            TextDrag.TranslateX = savedTransform.TranslateX; ;
        }

        else if (TextTopLeft.Y < GridTopLeft.Y || TextBottomRight.Y > GridBottomRight.Y)
        {
            // Out of bounds on Y axis - Revert to copied Y transform
            TextDrag.TranslateY = savedTransform.TranslateY;
        }

        else
        {
            // TextBlock is within bounds - Copy X and Y Transform
            CopyTransform(transform, savedTransform);
        }
    }
```

Here it is in action.
[image: Here it is in action]

Comment: Thanks you sooo much @Mr.Adam McMahon. It's really helpful to me.

Comment: No problem. If this answer solved your problem then I'd be grateful if you could mark this as the correct answer. Thanks.